# Keras Conv2D and input channels

Tags: python, keras

The Keras layer documentation specifies the input and output sizes for convolutional layers:
https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/

Input shape: `(samples, channels, rows, cols)`

Output shape: `(samples, filters, new_rows, new_cols)`

And the kernel size is a spatial parameter, i.e. detemines only width and height.

So an input with `c` channels will yield an output with `filters` channels regardless of the value of `c`. It must therefore apply 2D convolution with a spatial `height x width` filter and then aggregate the results somehow for each learned filter.

What is this aggregation operator? is it a summation across channels? can I control it? I couldn't find any information on the Keras documentation.

- Note that in TensorFlow the filters are specified in the depth channel as well:
  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Convolution,
  So the depth operation is clear.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to read [this](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/).

Comment: From this page: "In the output volume, the d-th depth slice (of size W2×H2) is the result of performing a valid convolution of the d-th filter over the input volume with a stride of SS, and then offset by d-th bias. ". So I still don't follow how these convolutions of a volume with a 2D kernel turn into a 2D result. Is the depth dimension reduced by summation?

Comment: "Example 1. For example, suppose that the input volume has size [32x32x3], (e.g. an RGB CIFAR-10 image). If the receptive field (or the filter size) is 5x5, then each neuron in the Conv Layer will have weights to a [5x5x3] region in the input volume, for a total of 5*5*3 = 75 weights (and +1 bias parameter). Notice that the extent of the connectivity along the depth axis must be 3, since this is the depth of the input volume." -

I guess you are missing it's 3D kernel [width, height, depth]. So the result is summation across channels.

Comment: @Nilesh Birari , my question is exactly how to know what Keras is doing. I guess it's summation, but how can I know for sure?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It might be confusing that it is called **Conv2D** layer (it was to me, which is why I came looking for this answer), because as Nilesh Birari commented:

> I guess you are missing it's 3D kernel [width, height, depth]. So the result is summation across channels.

Perhaps the **2D** stems from the fact that the kernel only *slides* along two dimensions, the third dimension is fixed and determined by the number of input channels (the input depth).

For a more elaborate explanation, read https://petewarden.com/2015/04/20/why-gemm-is-at-the-heart-of-deep-learning/

I plucked an illustrative image from there:

[image: kernel depth]

Comment: So do each channel of the filter have their own weights which can be optimized? Or do we just compute the weights for one channel and use that as values for the rest of the channels of the filter.

Comment: The kernels are different for all channels. See my answer.

Comment: @Regi According to remykarem's answer, your statement is wrong.

Answer (score 44):

I was also wondering this, and found another answer [here](http://machinelearninguru.com/computer_vision/basics/convolution/convolution_layer.html), where it is stated (emphasis mine):

> Maybe the most tangible example of a multi-channel input is when you have a color image which has 3 RGB channels. Let's get it to a convolution layer with 3 input channels and 1 output channel. (...) What it does is that it calculates the convolution of each filter with its corresponding input channel (...). The stride of all channels are the same, so they output matrices with the same size. Now, **it sums up all matrices and output a single matrix which is the only channel** at the output of the convolution layer.

Illustration:

[image]

Notice that the **weights of the convolution kernels for each channel are different**, which are then iteratively adjusted in the back-propagation steps by e.g. gradient decent based algorithms such as stochastic gradient descent (SDG).

Here is a more technical answer from [TensorFlow API](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/tf.nn.conv2d.md).

Answer (score 41):

I also needed to convince myself so I ran a simple example with a 3×3 RGB image.

```
# red    # green        # blue
1 1 1    100 100 100    10000 10000 10000
1 1 1    100 100 100    10000 10000 10000    
1 1 1    100 100 100    10000 10000 10000
```

The filter is initialised to ones:

```
1 1
1 1
```

[image]

I have also set the convolution to have these properties:

- no padding
- strides = 1
- relu activation function
- bias initialised to 0

We would expect the (aggregated) output to be:

```
40404 40404
40404 40404
```

Also, from the picture above, the no. of parameters is

3 separate filters (one for each channel) × 4 weights + 1 (bias, not shown) = **13 parameters**

---

Here's the code.

Import modules:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D
from keras.models import Model
```

Create the red, green and blue channels:

```
red   = np.array([1]*9).reshape((3,3))
green = np.array([100]*9).reshape((3,3))
blue  = np.array([10000]*9).reshape((3,3))
```

Stack the channels to form an RGB image:

```
img = np.stack([red, green, blue], axis=-1)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
```

Create a model that just does a Conv2D convolution:

```
inputs = Input((3,3,3))
conv = Conv2D(filters=1, 
              strides=1, 
              padding='valid', 
              activation='relu',
              kernel_size=2, 
              kernel_initializer='ones', 
              bias_initializer='zeros', )(inputs)
model = Model(inputs,conv)
```

Input the image in the model:

```
model.predict(img)
# array([[[[40404.],
#          [40404.]],

#         [[40404.],
#          [40404.]]]], dtype=float32)
```

Run a summary to get the number of params:

```
model.summary()
```

[image]

Comment: EXCELLENT contribution

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Honestly I think the name conv2d is very confusing.

Comment: So, I am not the only one who started to wonder what's actually happening there and what does the underlying aggregation look like?

Comment: I find your statement "3 separate filters (one for each channel) " problematic. Conceptually, it is **one** filter that happens to span *n=number of input channels* channels. One filter therefore has *H*W*num_input_channels* parameters (not accounting for bias - in PyTorch, you have one bias per filter). When using this nomenclature, the number of filters equals the number of output channels after the convolution.